# Can I assign document.getElementById to variable in javascript

Tags: javascript, document, getelementbyid

I think `document.getElementById` is a function.

So this function can be assigned to variable. Like this

```js
var hello = document.getElementById;
console.log(hello('hello')));
```

```html
<div id="hello">hello</div>
```

But It occurred error like this:

> Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: `var hello = document.getElementById('hello');` `console.log(hello)`

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: The method must know on which `Document` instance you want it to be called. Probably, it's `document`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue is context. When you take the reference to the function, you lose the function's context to `document`. So, in order to do what you are trying to, you need to `bind` the context:

```
var hello = document.getElementById.bind(document);
```

**Working example:**

```js
var hello = document.getElementById.bind(document);
console.log(hello('hello'));
```

```html
<div id="hello">hello</div>
```

Comment: `::document.getElementById` will be nice

Answer (score 3):

Wrap it as a function with a parameter which represents the ID.

```js
var hello = function(id){
     return document.getElementById(id);
}
console.log( hello('hello')  );
```

```html
<div id="hello">hello</div>
```